# Can the Hamiltonian be upscaled to speed up quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-information, hamiltonian, quantum-computer

In quantum computing, gates are performed unitarily, i.e. $|\psi\rangle \mapsto U|\psi\rangle$, driven by some Hamiltonian, i.e. $U = \exp(-iHt)$. Consider $H$ as time independent, if it is proportionally scaled up, i.e. $H \mapsto \gamma H$, then the time for applying $U$ would become shorter, i.e., $t \mapsto \frac{t}{\gamma}$, does this speed up computation? (similar to how a classical computer can be overclocked)

Comment: When you overclock your CPU two twice the frequency, will it do computations twice as fast?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It does not allow me to overclock beyond a certain threshold because it overheats, I guess quantum computing has such constraints too, from Zalcman's answer it seems to be primarily error correction problems.

Comment: Well, why would overheating be a problem, if not because of causing errors in some way or the other (or setting your apartment on fire, of course!). Or because the CPU shuts down because it has a built-in protection. At some point also in the QC, the control electronics might overheat. Or the qubit. Energy dissipation grows with frequency in any setup. But yes, currently the biggest problems are probably errors. Though, if you had arbitrarily precise control on your classical pulses ... (which again would require higher frequency in your classical control) ...

Comment: I guess the point of my comment was: There is no fundamental difference here between classical and QC: You can make things faster by doing them faster, but there are practical (and sometimes more fundamental architecture-dependent) limitations to how fast you can get. And going faster requires more energy, which has to come from somewhere as well.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch A new question came up from this: If the Hamiltonian $H$ is the speed of traveling from one state to the other, then how does it compare to lightspeed? This echos back to a prior question [can-the-hamiltonian-be-interpreted-as-the-speed-of-unitary-evolution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620306/can-the-hamiltonian-be-interpreted-as-the-speed-of-unitary-evolution).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this sounds like just arbitrarily combining words. I'm not sure what the meaning is. If you have a question, ask it, but be clear about what you mean (e.g. when you say "H is the speed of traveling" -- What?? Speed is distance/time, at least if you want to compare it to light speed.)

Comment: Note that there is no light speed in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics. But Lieb-Robinson-bounds might be of interest in this context (or not, I don't think I understand the question).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ok sorry, I should be more clear, when I say "speed" I meant generator of evolution (as in the link's answer). Just wanted to know if there is a "speed" limit to state evolution like light speed for macroscopic travel. edit: I think Lieb-Robinson bounds is the answer, thank you.

Comment: LR-bounds indeed link interaction strength to speed (in units of the lattice constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the simplified model of time-independent Hamiltonian $H$ effecting a quantum gate $U=\exp(-iHt)$ multiplying $H$ by a constant factor $\gamma > 1$ does shorten the gate's duration.

In practice, physics constants, material properties, control electronics etc constrain what Hamiltonians can be engineered on any given hardware platform. For example, in architectures based superconducting qubits where engineers have a high degree of control over a large number of parameters that go into the Hamiltonian, the energy scale is generally constrained to the microwave spectrum.

---

Also note that while fast gates are preferable to slow gates with the same decoherence because faster gates allow us to run longer algorithms, very high gate speed becomes a mixed blessing when implementing quantum error correction because that entails the need for a classical computer running alongside the quantum device for decoding syndrome measurements. Very fast quantum gates make it more challenging to implement the classical computer to perform quantum error correction.